# In R, extract data from one data frame into another based on matching row values

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Below is a simplified version of what I'm looking to do (concepts are the same, data is different)

I have two data frames of different length.

DF1 has two columns (Name and State Abbreviation) and 1,000 rows

DF2 has two columns (State Abbreviation and State Name) and 50 rows

In DF1 I want to add a column called State Name

I want R to look at the State Abbreviation in DF1 and then find the corresponding State Name in DF2 (using the State Abbreviation column in DF2)

Note that the new column in DF1 can be called anything

Comment: Looks suspiciously like homework question...

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Since this looks like homework and is a fairly basic R question, its hard to believe that you have tried to find the answer on your own before posting here.

Comment: Not a homework problem, but it certainly does look like it.  I'm just new to R and can easily perform this in excel; I'm just trying to migrate all my data analysis work away from excel.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`?merge`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/merge.html) for this:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(name=c('n1','n2','n3','n4'), state.abbr=c('s1','s2','s2','s1'))
> df2 <- data.frame(state.abbr=c('s1','s2'), state.name=c('state 1', 'state 2'))
> merge(df1, df2)
  state.abbr name state.name
1         s1   n1    state 1
2         s1   n4    state 1
3         s2   n2    state 2
4         s2   n3    state 2
```

Comment: The problem is that in my reference data frame (DF2) I have a lot of additional columns that I do not want merged into DF1.

Comment: @user2148746: Extract just the columns you want: `df2[,c('state.abbr', 'state.name')]`

Comment: Thanks NPE, however, that just merged all the information from the reference data frame without necessary matching based on a specific column

Comment: @user2148746, there's a certain threshold of handholding that can be expected. See some of the examples under `?merge` to get a better understanding of how `merge` is supposed to work. If that still fails you, edit your *question* with `dput(head(YOUR-DATA-FRAMES))` and you might find people who are willing to help further.